# Missing files in git index

Tags: git, git-add, repo, git-status

I work on a git repo with many many branches in it.
Now i wanted to add a new feature from another location.
So i did `cp -r /source /target`
The new files are in my repo, but git ignores them.
If i do `git status` after i copied that files, git says 'working directory clean'...
Why this happens? It is not ignored in `.gitignore`.
I tried this also with other files, these files appear immediately in git status. What i did wrong and how i can fix this?

I read the other answers, but cant't find answers which helped.

Comment: Can you add the exact names of your files/directory and the content of your .gitignore file ?

Comment: file names are in ~/sites/project/typo3conf/ext/tagger
and .gitignore contents are here: http://pastebin.com/iJULC0p2

I dont think thats related with this problem because i added other files into the .../ext/ directory - that works. But have a look.

Comment: That's juste the `tagger`repo that is ignored ? You're right, can't see the reason in your `.gitignore`file... Maybe have a look at this : http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files

Comment: yes, only the tagger folder is ignored.
I tried to add another directory. This appears directly as change in git.

Comment: Have you tried to put the `tagger` repo in a different location ? Like at the root of your project, just to see what happens ?

Comment: Oh, i think i found whats going wrong.
I i copied the tagger dir, there was also an .git dir. I deleted this after the copy. I think git made a submodule from this. So, now i have to look how to clean up this.

Comment: Are you saying that just removing the `.git` repo made `tagger` appear as a change ?

Comment: no, i didnt had a look what happens directly after copying the tagger dir into my repo. I saw a few minutes later that there is also a .git dir in tagger.
So i removed that. And later, if i wanted to commit the changes, i saw there isnt the new tagger dir to add.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons in order of likelihood:

- `/target` isn't inside your working directory
- One of the new folders is in `.gitignore` (which makes Git ignore all files in it).
- You're looking in the wrong ignore file. Check your global ignore files: `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`, `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`, `.gitignore`
- You can have one `.gitignore` per folder. Check all the folders.
- The files already existed with the exact same content

To debug the issue, try `git check-ignore`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

Comment: thanks, but all theses things i checked before i post my question ;)

Comment: Try `git check-ignore`